# Non-integer Flash frame rates bug using swfutils as part of flex -- is there a better swf parser out there?

Tags: flash

I'm using swfutils 4.6 to find get information about uploaded Flash files in our application.

The problem is that a user has tried to upload a Flash file with a non-integer frame rate, in this case, 12.5, and the SWFParser cannot handle it properly and decides the frame rate is 32760!

This seems to happen for all non-integer frame rates.

Is there a way around this?

Does anyone know of a better SWF parser?

swfutils is issued by Adobe, so I assume it's reasonably good except for this bug.

Comment: I'm using TagDecoder to do the parsing: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/flex/sdk/trunk/modules/swfutils/src/java/flash/swf/TagDecoder.java?view=markup

Comment: The number you're getting is probably 32780, that is 0x80 << 8 | 0x0C. 0x0C is 12. 0x80 is the fractional part, in this case half of 256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform by Flagstone seems to work better, at the very least handling non-integer frame rates much better.

Here's more information: http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/transform/index.html